# Подключение php файлов при помощи javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Подскажите как при помощи javascript (или AJAX) можно реализовать подключение определенного php скрипта, т.е. есть список (select) в котором название различных файлов php (A.php, B.php, C.php) и нужно что бы когда пользователь выберал из этого списка файл (допустим B.php) он подключался при помощи include.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@gooda](/users/10217/gooda) подключение определенного php скрипта можно, как пример, реализовать при помощи проверки GET, POST, etc... условий. Вот наглядный пример:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['include']) && $_GET['include'] == 'inc.php') {
   include('inc.php');
}
?>
```

А уж как вызывать это - через ajax, аль просто запросов - ваше дело.

Comment: ну да, так уже и сделал, просто думал может еще есть какой то другой способ :)

Comment: Ну, почитайте про MVC фрэймворки.
Попробуйте понять как они работают :)

Comment: @Станислав Комар а фреймворк будет тем же самым include, только в 100500 обернутых функций. А вы что думали, магия работает?

Comment: @lampa зато вопросы будут правильно формулироваться, и возможно решение будет приходить в голову само собой

Answer (score 0):

А для этого необходимо понять принцип работы PHP :)
Как только Вы поймете - вопрос сам по себе исчезнет :)

Comment: принцип работы php я понимаю и понимаю что php серверный язык а js выполняется на стороне клиента, но допустим можно что бы через js передовался параметр на эту же страницу и через _GET подлючать php файл...

Comment: @gooda, не вижу проблемы.